# Last-Modified not working for .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, header, http-headers, httpd.conf

I'm tyring to implement browser caching and follow Google PageSpeed's recommendation about setting Last-Modified to a data that is "sufficiently far enough in the past." I have the following in my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
 <FilesMatch "\.(json|pdf|swf|bmp|gif|jpeg|jpg|png|svg|tiff|ico|flv|js)$">
  Header Set Last-Modified "Fri, 01 Jan 2010 12:00:00 GMT"
 </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

I have mod_headers installed on my server.

Unfortunately, Google PageSpeed still complains and warns me:

```
Leverage browser caching

The following cacheable resources have a short freshness lifetime. Specify an expiration at least one week in the future for the following resources:
```

And then lists PNGs, GIFs, JPGs, etc. Yahoo YSlow says basically the same thing.

Looking at the response headers of one of my resources that should be caching, I see this:

```
Date:           Tue, 19 Oct 2010 20:12:04 GMT
Server:         Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified:  Tue, 07 Sep 2010 23:51:33 GMT
Etag:           "2e0e34-2a43-48fb413a96a20"
Accept-Ranges:  bytes
Content-Length: 10819
Content-Type:   image/png
```

As you can see, the Last-Modified data does not match what I specified in .htaccess.

**Any ideas what I am doing wrong?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered just using unset Last-Modified?

Example:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
 <FilesMatch "\.(json|pdf|swf|bmp|gif|jpeg|jpg|png|svg|tiff|ico|flv|js)$">
  Header unset Last-Modified
 </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

The FilesMatch section looks fine, so it's probably just some fiddly bit with Header Set. Hell, might even be case sensitive. Try `Header set` instead of `Header Set`

If this isn't what you want, then let me know and I'll think about it a bit more. Unset should work though,

Comment: I tried `Header set`; it did nothing. Then I tried `Header unset Last-Modified`; that also did nothing. My .htaccess seems to ignore header directives, but respects compression (DEFLATE) directives. Any more ideas?

Comment: Actually, I just commented out my compression directives. However, the resources are still being served as compressed. Now, I think I am more lost than when I started.

Comment: If you're comfortable doing it, would you mind editing your original post to include the whole .htaccess file? I'd like to look at the whole thing, if I could.

Comment: Never mind. Turns out, something in the server was preventing it. Admin fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Removing `Last-Modified` is not what Google PageSpeed is asking. It wants to see the following headers in your servers response when browsers asks for static files:

```
Cache-Control max-age=...
Expires ...
```

in place of dots the server will place values.

In order to do this, you simply need to add to `.htaccess` the following lines:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
 <FilesMatch "\.(json|pdf|swf|bmp|gif|jpeg|jpg|png|svg|tiff|ico|flv|js)$">
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
  Header append Cache-Control "public"
 </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

You'll see Google PageSpeed stopping to complain.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On 
# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
# My favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
# Images
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
# Javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Could you explain what the solution involves?